# Perform multiple http calls in a Parse Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So, basically I have to call a cloud function hosted on **Parse.com** that:

1. perform a first http call
2. convert the result(json) into a list of objects
3. do another http call and modify the list of objects with the information provided by the second http call.
4. return the elaborated json

I've read about Promises [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-introduction-to-promises) but I can't figure out how I can do something like that..

This is my Main.js file..

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getSolutions", function(request, response) {

  var _idDepartureStation, _idArrivalStation, _departureTime, _dateTime;
  _idDepartureStation = request.params.idDepartureStation;
  _idArrivalStation = request.params.idArrivalStation;
  _departureTime = request.params.departureTime;
  _dateTime = request.params.dateTime;

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: API_SEARCH_SOLUTION.replace("{IDDEPARTURESTATION}",_idDepartureStation).replace("{IDARRIVALSTATION}",_idArrivalStation).replace("{DEPARTURETIME}",_departureTime)
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    // success first call
    console.log("First call");
    return httpResponse.text;
  },function(httpResponse) {
    // error second call
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    response.error(httpResponse.status);
  }).then(function(firstResponse){
    // second call
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: API_STATION_STATUS.replace("{IDSTATION}",_idDepartureStation).replace("{TYPE}","partenze").replace("{DATETIME}",_dateTime)
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
      // success second call
      console.log("Second call");
      return "First: " + firstResponse + "\nSecond: "+httpResponse.text;
    },function(httpResponse) {
      // error second call
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
      response.error(httpResponse.status);
    })
  }).then(function(result){
    response.success(result);
  });
});
```

I know that is wrong.. but I've still not clear how Promises works..

From my logs I can see that only "First call" is printed and the result of the function is undefined.

Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you share the code?

Comment: Here's the code! ;) Thanks

Comment: Can you change `succes` to `success` ?

Comment: Damn you're right! Changed! Ok now result is equal to undefined and in the logs I see only "First call" then nothing..